# Get GMSAddress from GMSPlace placeID

Tags: ios, google-maps

Is there any way to get `GSMAddress` from placeID. I am interested in getting the address by using the `placeID` obtained from `autocompleteQuery` method.

P.S: I have a `placeID` and finding a way to get corresponding `GMSAddress` in iOS.

I found a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106534/how-to-get-gmsaddress-from-placeid-or-gmsplace) but that does not help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After autocomplete, we do a place look up, then pass the coordinates to GMSGeocoder to retrieve the details, but I am still missing street_name and street_number.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D addressCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude);

GMSGeocoder* coder = [[GMSGeocoder alloc] init];
[coder reverseGeocodeCoordinate:addressCoordinates completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *results, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@", error.description);
    } else {
        GMSAddress* address = [results firstResult];
        NSLog(@"thoroughfare %@",address.thoroughfare);
        NSLog(@"locality %@",address.locality);
        NSLog(@"subLocality %@",address.subLocality);
        NSLog(@"administrativeArea %@",address.administrativeArea);
        NSLog(@"postalCode %@",address.postalCode);
        NSLog(@"country %@",address.country);
        NSLog(@"lines %@",address.lines);
    }
}];
```

I'm thinking of switching to iOS's own reverse geocoder.

```
[CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude] completionHandler:
 ^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error) {
```

Comment: I want exactly opposite things. get lat long from address.. Hows it possible from GMSGeocoder !!

Comment: This can get street name and street number. See my answer in swift 4.1 Xcode 9.4.1. You can get even village name details also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647996/get-location-name-from-latitude-longitude-in-ios/51797299#51797299

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no direct way to get the `GSMAddress` from `GMSPlace` placeID.

One way that I figured out is to use `GMSGeocoder().reverseGeocodeCoordinate` method along with `coordinate` property from `GMSPlace`.

The steps I followed can be summed as:

1. Use `lookUpPlaceID` method to find the `coordinates`
2. Reverse geocode using the `coordinates` obtained from `lookUpPlaceID`

Code is as follows:

```
    placesClient?.lookUpPlaceID(placeID, callback: {
        (place, error) -> Void in
        // Get place.coordinate
        GMSGeocoder().reverseGeocodeCoordinate(place!.coordinate, completionHandler: {
            (response, error) -> Void in
            for addObj in response.results() {
                // Address object
            }
        })
    })
```

Comments and better solutions are welcome.

Comment: Only issue I have is not being able to get the street_number separated from the street_name. See below in my code snippet

Comment: @ bendigi, please see my answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647996/get-location-name-from-latitude-longitude-in-ios/51797299#51797299